# Symfony 5.x - What is the point of the alias logic?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, symfony5, ezpublish, ibexa

I'm working on the migration of a project from Symfony 3.x to 5.4.
It's based on a CMS (Ibexa) and came across the deprecation :

```
 Cannot autowire service "MyClient\Bundle\Manager\MyManager": argument "$fieldHelper" of method "__construct()" references class "eZ\Publish\Core\Helper\FieldHelper" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "ezpublish.fi
  eld_helper" service.
```

I solved it by declaring in my services.yaml :

```
bind:
    eZ\Publish\Core\Helper\FieldHelper: ezpublish.field_helper
```

I'm confused as to the point of this change at the framework level. Why do I need to add an alias for an already registered service - that came in the package I'm using ? I fail to see the benefits.
Is there a better solution to use it out of the box ?

Comment: I'm guessing that your MyManager service had been manually defined in 3.x and is now being autowired.  Autowire goes by class name.  Even though ezpublish.field_helper uses the FieldHelper class there could be other FieldHelper based services so autowire won't use it automatically.  BTW, technically binds are not aliases.  Bit surprised it worked.  See the docs for how to make an actual alias if you want.

Comment: Also beware of this package because it is not maintain since 2017. So you will have a lot of problem if you want to upgrade to php 7+ or 8+ anyway. Which are much better php version.

Comment: @Cerad MyManager service wasn't explicitly defined. Now in 5.x I do have to define it manually. But when you say "ezpublish.field_helper uses the FieldHelper" it's more than usage I would say since it's a direct reference/alias to "eZ\Publish\Core\Helper\FieldHelper". Since the FQN is used how could it reference an other class ?

Comment: Multiple services using the same class can be defined.  Which explains why autowire does not rely on the service's class.  Autowire justs uses the actual string to match service ids.  Autowire neither knows nor cares that a service id is a FQN. As to why it used to work, that seems to be a bit of a mystery.  Something in your upgrade process.

Comment: And I am still quite confused how `bind` got any of this to work.  Bind uses variable names not class names.  Could be there is some other configuration going on.

Comment: Clarification : the error isn't showing anymore. Stating that it's "working" _might be_ an overstatement since I'm still in the middle of fixing deprecations. Regarding the `bind` use, I followed this https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-fundamentals/slack-autowiring-alias